# Syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I am missing the PHP, XML and SQL syntax highlighting when using the code formatting, which we do have in StackOverflow.

For example: [Find out to which categories a product belongs to](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/71/84)

None of the two answers have any highlighting.

Excuse me if this is already being discussed or if I missed something...

Comment: Maybe because it's a private beta site so it doesn't have a proper css and every thing *activate*. I guess this will be fixed when the public beta will be out or when the website will be public.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer can be found [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/461/no-syntax-highlighting-in-glu).

> Syntax highlighting is not enabled by default when a site launches to beta.

Comment: Why though?  The german meta answer doesn't really explain it that well.  Is there a SE meta answer for it?  I can't figure how it's at all useful to have it disabled during a beta.

Comment: By default, suggesting there is a way to manually turn them on?

Comment: Hey we're out of beta, time for syntax highlighting?