# Syntax Highlighting now that we're out of beta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

This was originally asked here: [Syntax highlighting](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11/2190)

But now that we're out of beta, I'll bring it up again, how do we get syntax highlighting turned on for PHP, XML, etc?

Comment: apparently we are not 100% out of beta : http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48872/magento

Comment: Well well....we are out of beta for good. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48872/magento. I guess this is a valid question now.

Comment: Summoning @Pops, maybe he can give us an insight.

Comment: Sorry for dropping the ball on this when graduation was happening... fixed now, though!

Answer (score 5):

Yay, thanks @Pops we now have syntax highlighting !! Champagne everyone!

Comment: I'll pm you my address to deliver the champagne

Comment: i don't drink can you send me money instead :P :D

Answer (score 0):

One extra hint for those who haven't worked with syntax highlighting on other SE sites (like Stack Overflow): you can specify its language if it doesn't already pick it up automatically:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting